# Interface Builder can't set accessibility traits (Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having a weird problem in Interface Builder (Xcode 8). Basically, I can't enable (select) accessibility traits; IB is rejecting my attempt.

For example, I have a UILabel which has the "static text" and "user interaction enabled" traits enabled. I can click the "static text" checkbox to disable it. But then when I click it again to re-enable it, the checkbox briefly shows a minus ("-") which then disappears, leaving the checkbox unchecked.

I don't know how to re-enable that checkbox (or any other). Any solutions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug introduced in Xcode 8, that affected inspector properties that map to bit mask properties. This includes iOS accessibility attributes, NSWindow style masks, and popover segue directions.

https://twitter.com/eternalstorms/status/776384102291431424

It's fixed in Xcode 8.3.

Answer (score 5):

This has happened to me once. Try restarting Xcode.

Comment: That was it! How simple... argh! Thanks much.

Comment: Np! You're amazed how much stuff is solved by just restarting Xcode lol

Comment: i still find the bug in xcode 8 (do they even fix them?) and when i restart xcode i'm able to set one or two of these traits, then the bug reappear...

Answer (score 0):

I still find the bug in xcode 8 (do they even fix them?) and when i restart xcode i'm able to set one or two of these traits, then the bug reappear... 
One way to deal with it is to edit the file "as source code":

- in the Project navigator panel right click on the xib file and "Open as -> Source code"
- find the block "